# Is it okay to declare a checked exception for an exception thrown by a called method?

Tags: java

Consider this:

```
public void Do() throws Exception {

 if (blah) throw new Exception(...);

 Thingy thingy = ...;

 Foo(thingy);
}

public void Foo(Thingy thingy) throws EmptyThingyException {

   if (thingy == null || 
     thingy.isEmpty()) throw new EmptyThingyException();

  ...
}

public class EmptyThingyException extends Throwable { ... }
```

In this case, is it okay to not handle `EmptyThingyException` inside `Do` and declare `Do` like so:

```
public void Do() throws Exception, EmptyThingyException {
```

or do I *have* to handle `EmptyThingyException` inside `Do` and throw it back again like so:

```
public void Do() throws Exception, EmptyThingyException {
    try {
    } catch (EmptyThingyException empty) {
      throw empty;
    }
    ...
  }
```

Comment: What would be the point in catching and rethrowing exactly the same exception? There are cases to do that, e.g. you want to propagate a specific exception but catch a generic exception; but you're not doing that here. Catching and rethrowing *isn't* handling.

Comment: @AndyTurner I know that. My question does not pertain to a concept as much as it does to syntax. All I asking is -- I can just declare the `throws TheExceptionThatAnotherMethodICalledThrows` as a part of the checked exception of the calling method, right? I tried and it looks like I can, so long as I explicitly `catch` every exception sub-type in the main top-level method.

Comment: Extending `Throwable` directly is not a particularly good idea. You should extend `Exception` (or a subclass of it) or in rare, truly catastrophic cases, `Error`. (But `Error` should really only be used for things that no reasonable application can handle.)

Comment: Are you asking whether you should declare `throws Exception, EmptyThingyException` vs `throws Exception` (which covers `EmptyThingyException`)?

Comment: You don't need to `catch` subtypes of exceptions thrown by called methods. In your example you have to list the "exception" explicitly because you've had it extend `Throwable` instead of `Exception`.

Comment: Note, some languages like C# does not use checked exception at all, and Java is using them only in special cases. So when you are writing such a code consider whether it is really needed to have checked exception.

Comment: @matoni C++17 is all but giving up on exception specifications though this is partly because of their weak enforcement in C++ that is not a feature of Java.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to the question is:

Yes, it's correct to declare a checked exception thrown by a called method.

How a method achieves its purpose is an implementation detail and it shouldn't matter to the interface how much it does directly or how much it delegates to methods. The language rules about checked exceptions are carefully defined to make sure methods advertise all checked exceptions they may throw or methods they call throw (but are not handled by the method itself). Letting an unhandled exception get 'thrown through' a method is how things are supposed to work.
Indeed the answer is in the name of the construct "non-local exception handling" it was conceived to take effort out of endless error handling all the way up a call chain when the only real action is "that didn't work" at some point near the start.

To align to that method, you should only `catch` exceptions you're going to do something about.
Clean up code should be achieved with `finally` so the normal reasons to `catch` an exception are to log it and/or abandon a task at some point rather than letting the stack unwind further.

In this specific case the best answer would be to throw an `IllegalArgumentException`:

```
throw new IllegalArgumentException("thingy==null || thingy.isEmpty()");
```

That's unchecked and wisely so. Correct code shouldn't encounter illegal arguments and they should expect to be thrown rarely and be indicative of program flaw (either in the class, it's package or consumer code). External and user input should be validated directly and programs shouldn't rely on `IllegalArgumentException`.

In practice `IllegalArgumentException` and `IllegalStateException` should cover 'internal errors' meaning "You can't do this with that" or "You can't do that right now" respectively and should be commented to specify the fault.

The idea that you might sub-class those two because consumer code might respond differently to different illegal actions it might take is bodging pure and simple.

Program correctness includes that a program never makes an illegal call on some other part of the program or enters an invalid or corrupted state and exceptions only occur as a result of environmental failures that mean a program or sub-task in a program cannot be completed as intended.

Answer (score 0):

if you **want to do something after exception happen**, then use `try-catch`, or you can just declare it on the method.

Beyond that, if `EmptyThingyException` is **sub class** of `Exception`, then it is no need to declare `EmptyThingyException` when you have declared `Exception`.

Comment: `EmptyThingyException` is a subclass of `Throwable`, not a subclass of `Exception`

Comment: NB: The OP has derived their exception from `Throwable`. That's not included in the scope `throws Exception`. It's also not recommended... The best answer is actually to throw an `IllegalArgumentException' and be done.

Answer (score 0):

**1- Declare the specific checked exceptions that your method can throw**

```
public void foo() throws Exception { //Incorrect way
}
```

Always avoid doing this as in above code sample. It simply defeats the whole purpose of having checked exception. Declare the specific checked exceptions that your method can throw. If there are just too many such checked exceptions, you should probably wrap them in your own exception and add information to in exception message. You can also consider code refactoring also if possible.

**2- Always catch only those exceptions that you can actually handle**

```
catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
   throw e; //Avoid this as it doesn't help anything
}
```

Well this is most important concept. Don’t catch any exception just for the sake of catching it. Catch any exception only if you want to handle it or, you want to provide additional contextual information in that exception. If you can’t handle it in catch block, then best advice is just don’t catch it only to re-throw it.

**3- Avoid using Throwable class**

Throwable is the superclass of Exception and Error, as far as I know you need to use Throwable when you want to deal with both exceptions and errors, but it's definitely not your concern here, most of the java code deal with Exception and it's the way to go whenever you need to deal with checked exceptions http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html.

**
Well if I was you I would do something like :

```
public void Do() throws BlahIsFoundException{
 try {
     if (blah) throw new BlahIsFoundException(...);

     Thingy thingy = ...;

     Foo(thingy);
 } catch(EmptyThingyException exception) {
     //Handle the exception correctly, at least log it
 } finally {
     //Do some clean up if needed, for example close a database connection or free some resources.
 }
}

public void Foo(Thingy thingy) throws EmptyThingyException {

   if (thingy == null || 
     thingy.isEmpty()) throw new EmptyThingyException();

  ...
}

public class EmptyThingyException extends Exception { ... }
public class BlahIsFoundException extends Exception { ... }
```

Hope that helps, here are some good documents to read :
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html 
http://howtodoinjava.com/best-practices/java-exception-handling-best-practices